# how to resolve errors in bert embedding installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model, embedding

```
import mxnet as mx
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\gpu3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\__init__.py", line 24, in 
<module>
from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\gpu3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\context.py", line 24, in 
<module>
from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\gpu3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 213, in 
<module>
_LIB = _load_lib()
File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\gpu3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 204, in 
_load_lib
lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\gpu3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

This is the error while import bert-embeddings it gets installed but while importing it gives error like above and the numpy version it installs is incompatible with other libraries.
[This link i am following .](https://github.com/hmohebbi/SentimentAnalysis/blob/master/main.ipynb)

Comment: Have you tried installing mxnet using `!pip install mxnet`? or follow [this](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.4.1/install/windows_setup.html) link for reference.

Comment: even after installation it gives me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mxnet' error